Bitbucket issue with git pull
So here is my situation... I have code that is stored on our local BitBucket server.  The repo in particular is one only I work on.  My last update to this code was back in May (and everything worked fine then).
So I made a code change and went to pull from the repo (my habit is to pull to make sure I have the latest code, just in case, before I push any changes up to the repo), and when I did, I got this error from GitKraken:

Then I tried a git pull command via dos shell prompt and got:
D:\Sites\SVRUTILS\classic.d8.dynamicbin.service>git pull
Unable to negotiate with 10.0.0.28 port 7999: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I had this occur with another repo - and the only way I got it working was to move my data to a new location (temp), delete the repo from my pc, clone it again from the bitbucket server, and then copy my changes back...
This seems a bit extreme and shouldn't be the case...
I've validated that my SSH connection is still the same key (they match what is in BitBucket)
Any ideas as to why BitBucket won't let me pull data down from repo's I haven't connected with in over 6 months??
At this point, I'm thinking of looking into other options such as gitlab, to store my code bases...

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+negotiate+no+matching+host+key+type+found

Can you ssh into the server? It should kick you out, but after establishing the ssh connection successfully (so you know that the certificate you are using is correct).

Over time the repos are being moved back & forth and their IP address changes. The error you have received looks exactly like that. In your .ssh folder you have a known_hosts file where you have an entry for each host you have contacted earlier. You will need to simply remove the line(s) that are likely deprecated, then you will be asked again whether you want to connect and after typing in yes, you should be good to go.
